# Node.js reference error : Classname is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file bloom.js which is as follows :

```
     function Bloom(k, m, n, hashFunction){

        if(!m)
            m = 1000

        this.m = m;

        if(!n)
            n = 100

        this.n = n;

        if(!k)
            k = Math.max(Math.round(m / n * Math.LN2), 1)

        this.k = k


        this.insert = function(string){

            for(var i = 0; i < this.k; i++){

                var index = parseInt(this.hashFunction(i + string), 16) % this.array.length

                this.array[index] = 1;
            }

            return true;
        }





    }
module.exports = Bloom;
```

In my main.js i am getting errors when doing this :

**var Bloom = require("./bloom");
var bloom = new Bloom();**

Error :

```
TypeError: Bloom is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (J:\code\Main.js:114:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

How can i resolve this error ? I tried exporting module too but it didnt worked.

Comment: Are you exporting the function Bloom from that file?

Comment: There is no `Bloom` variable in your `main.js` module. `require` is not an `#include` that pastes all sources into your code, it just returns a reference to the modules exported values.

Comment: Using `require` on a file does not automatically move all of the items from that file into your current context. `Bloom` needs to be exported, and you still need to import it (using `require` in some form or another).

Comment: @JaredSmith please check editted question

Comment: @DivyanshuPathania: The contents of the `Bloom` function don't matter. Show us the code with `module.exports`. Also it probably should be `new bf` or `new bf.Bloom`, not `new Bloom`, if `bf` is the name you're importing it under.

Comment: @Bergi HI , please see updated question. I tried with new bf.Bloom() too , but its a same error

Comment: You need to read documentation before posting here. That is not at all how you use node.js. Please consult a node.js tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
// bloom.js
   function Bloom(k, m, n, hashFunction){

    if(!m)
        m = 1000

    this.m = m;

    if(!n)
        n = 100

    this.n = n;

    if(!k)
        k = Math.max(Math.round(m / n * Math.LN2), 1)

    this.k = k


    this.insert = function(string){

        for(var i = 0; i < this.k; i++){

            var index = parseInt(this.hashFunction(i + string), 16) % this.array.length

            this.array[index] = 1;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
module.exports = Bloom;
```

Then, in main.js:

```
// NOTE! the variable name here is what matters, not what you defined in bloom.js
var Bloom = require("./bloom");
var bloom = new Bloom();
```

Comment: your edited question still looks like you're not following the recommendation. See my expanded recommendation on your code.

Comment: now i am getting TypeError: Bloom is not a function is not a function .

Comment: Are main.js and bloom.js in the same folder?

Comment: They are in same folder

Comment: I can copy and paste the above into main.js and bloom.js and they work just fine.  There's something about your setup that you're not telling us.  What do you get when you run node --version from the command line?

Comment: Also, is this J drive a network drive?  Windows sometimes gives problems trying to do anything code-like on a network drive (e.g. I could not even use it as the default home for Visual Studio projects).

Comment: Node.js version is 4.4.3